# migrating TFS data to SQL Server 2008 for reporting

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

We are developing a reporting sytem which actually consolidates project related data (Bugs, Issues, Testcases) from different systems like TFS,svn etc. so that managerial guys can diffrent kind of reports of any project.

For this purpose we want TFS data to move to our SQL Server database because, as per our understanding we can't access TFS database directly in the production environment.

Can we use the TFS api to Transfer the data or is any other efficient method available?

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

TFS runs on SQL Server. As long as you have the necessary permissions, you can access it.

Comment: As per my understnding we don't have permission to access tfs warehouse in production environment